# Fetch JSON data for authenticated user login

Tags: php, json, react-native

I am trying to fetch signup details for authenticated user login in react native.
But its not working. I am new to react native so can anybody say what wrong i am doing.

**Index.js**

```js
onPressLogin()
{
    this.setState({
        isLoading: true,
        error: '',
    });
    dismissKeyboard();
    fetch('http://10.0.2.2/movies/signup.php' ,{
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept' : 'application/json' ,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
        },
        body : JSON.stringify({
            contact : this.state.contact,
            password: this.state.password
        })
    }).then((response) => 
    {
        return response.json(); 
    }).then((response) => {
        if(response.json){
         const routeStack = this.props.navigator.getCurrentRoutes();
         this.props.navigator.jumpTo(routeStack[3]);
         AsyncStorage.multiSet([
         [ 'contact' , response.contact],
         ]);
        } else {
            alert("Invalid login");
        }
    });
}
```

I am using PHP as backend.

**Signup.php**

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
$check_json = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo $obj1=json_decode($check_json);
$contact=$obj1 ->{"contact"};
$pass=$obj1 ->{"password"};
$prep = $mysqli->prepare("select contact,password from signup where 
contact=? and password=?");
$prep->bind_param("ss",$contact,$pass);
$prep->execute();
echo $result1=$prep->get_result();
$count= $result1->num_rows();
    if($count>0){          
         echo '1';
    }
   else{
       echo'0';
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: change `method: 'GET'` to `method: 'POST'`?

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text!**. Only store password hashes! Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Answer (score 0):

There is no json data on http://10.0.2.2/movies/signup.php..Encode your data in json.You can also try axios for fetching the json data.If you are using local server then show the json encoded output please.